# How to concatenate numerous df's pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

This is similar to a few questions regarding this topic.

I have a `df` for each `day` in the `month`. the `df's` are exported daily and I want to `concatenate` them to create a `monthly` `df`. I'm currently performing this via the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')#1st
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')#2nd
df3 = pd.read_csv('df3.csv')#3rd ect

concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

I repeat this 30 odd times. Is there a more efficient way to `concatenate` these `df's` if the initial `df` in the `directory` is the first day of the month and the final `df` is the last day of the month.

As in;

For directory `'month'`
`concatenate` all files?

Rather than `reading` each individual `df` and `concatenating` 30 odd `df's`

Comment: Use a list comprehension like `concat_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('df{}.csv'.format(i) for i in range(1,31)])`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

allFiles = glob.glob(os.getcwd()+ "/*.csv")
list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list_)
print(frame)
```

Similar - [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: Use this op, I use it almost everyday!